# Handle deploy to multiple server by capistrano with keep same version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-deployment, capistrano

I am ruby on rails developer, I receive a question interview about deployment use capistrano, example if I have three server A, B, C. I know config help capistrano deploy to three server. But interviewer ask me what happen if deployment on server A is finished, but while server B is deploying and user accesses to server B and C and sees different with other user uses server A because server A is now uses new version of code. How to handle this case ?